# Active state for static categories menu

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on a store with a small amount of categories and for the purpose of tayloring the drop down menu li's with bg images and descriptions, I want to markup the top.phtml manually.

After searching high and low I'm posting here to know if anyone can point me in the right direction for adding active class to the current category/parent category?

Much obliged,

Peter

Comment: Do you mean `top.links.phtml`? And could you post the code you have?

Comment: I meant the top.phtml that's under catalog/navigation/. The ones I tried are;

`<?php if(!Mage::registry('current_category')):?>active<?php endif;?>"`
`<?php if (rtrim(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(), '/') === rtrim($this->getUrl('category'), '/')):?>active<?php endif;?>`

I now reverted to using what classes & ids are available out of the box to do my styling etc but would be great to have the correct m.o for another time.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options here.

#1, You can let the menu render itself and then do string finds and replaces to mark it up better.

#2, You can compare the requested url to category url fragments to determine which ones are active.

I've used a combination of the two to create menus with CMS pages and certain categories with different CSS classes etc.